# What context.DeserializeTicket(token) does?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, access-token

I am trying to understand how refresh token works, and I have a pretty good idea, here an example  http://bit.ly/1n9Tbot,  but I found this `context.DeserializeTicket(protectedTicket);` 
I am not sure what it does, and practically doesn't have any documentation as you can see here http://bit.ly/1y7LTHt

[image]

Is it use to destroy the token? if it is to "deserialize", why does not return anything?

Comment: It is rather mysterious isn't it.

Comment: I have it in my ReceiveAsync function in my implementation of IAuthenticationTokenProvider. There is a mirror function above in CreateAsync where  "token.ProtectedTicket = context.SerializeTicket()"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
context.DeserializeTicket()
```

is similar to

```
context.SetTicket()
```

in that they both set the context's ticket.

The difference is that *DeserializeTicket* takes a string, which is a serialized ticket.

This is useful for me because I save the serialized ticket (*context.SerializeTicket()*) in my database.

Comment: I am using my own implementation of refresh tokens, as I am not serializing the authentication ticket while generating refresh token, I am using a guid to set as a refresh token and in Create method I simply save a Guid in db and return the guid as the refresh token to user (context.setToken(guidString)); Now In Receive method, how can I reject the request if token is not valid? There is no Context.SetError in this

Comment: @HamzaKhanzada You should create a new question for your problem. This question is "What context.DeserializeTicket(token) does?".